# Accurately reporting referrer from payments made with PayPal in Google Analytics

Tags: php, zend-framework, paypal, google-analytics

In our Google Analytics ecommerce PayPal is getting credit as the referrer. I've found many articles outlining use on the utmnooveride to ensure PayPal transactions pass the data so that the original referrer gets credit.

We use PayPal to process our credit cards as well as allow people to pay with their PayPal account. When a visitor pays with credit card they never leave our site, so we are only seeing this inaccuracy when a user leaves our site to pay with their PayPal account.

More accurately we are using PayPal express checkout and using NVP (name value pair) API. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/

We've implemented the suggestions and code changes we have found but PayPal is still getting credit.
We've even talked with PayPal and Google techs and aren't getting any thing more from them than what we are finding online.

Is anyone else encountering this issue, have you found a solution or have any suggestions? Your help is much appreciated.

**-- Solution Update --**

**Moved to the answers.**

Comment: This stuff is really implementation specific, so it's very difficult to give specific instructions without knowing a lot of details. How did you implement the `utm_nooverride` param?

Comment: Two different uses inside our cart code: in the new two comments for readability

Comment: `'return url'=> $server_name.'/cart/paypal?utm_nooverride=1'`

Comment: `'Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('ordercomplete');
$ordercomplete_session = new 
Zend_Session_Namespace('ordercomplete');
$ordercomplete_session->order_id = $order->id;
$redirect = '/ordercomplete/'.$order->id.'?utm_nooverride=1';
return $this->_redirect($redirect);`

Comment: So `/cart/paypal?utm_nooverride=1` never renders, but HTTP redirects to `/ordercomplete/SOME-ORDER-ID?utm_nooverride=1`, right? In GA, what landing pages are you seeing from Paypal traffic (if it's only `utm_nooverride` not working, it should be just a bunch of `/ordercomplete/...`)?

Comment: From my understanding that is how it should work. I am seeing the /ordercompete for some, but seeing more that aren't hitting the ordercomplete.

Comment: Ah, most likely people who don't actually complete the payment with Paypal. What's the split (traffic-wise) between the conversion page and the other pages? If the user (at any point) gets redirected back to your site withouth the `utm_nooverride` param, Paypal may be set as the traffic source from that point.

Comment: So are you saying that people come from sourceX click the pay with PayPal hit cancel, so then PayPal gets the referral source, then finalize checkout with a credit card?

To answer your question, it's a significant portion > 50% of PayPal referrers that are hitting a page other than order complete.

If you are correct, is there a way to eliminate PayPal for being marked a a referral? To that, I am thinking we actually have it marked as utm_noooveride=1 on the cancel action.

Comment: Yeah, I would add the `utm_nooverride` to all return links (completed transaction, cancel, error). The list of pages with the PayPal referrer should be good place to start. Have you checked your server's access logs, to see if the `utm_nooverride` is actually present on the `/ordercomplete` page?

Comment: Can you post your solution as an Answer? You might need a bit more reputation to do so, but you've clearly researched this well, and found a solution. I'm upvoting, partially to give you more points so you can Answer your own post, and partially from respect at the work you've done and the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: JezC - thanks for the compliments and the up vote. I have moved the solution to an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Per request.. I am moving the answer from a followup in the question to the actual answer.

Based on some various articles on how to improve accuracy of data reporting I just happened to be messing with property settings in Analytics and came across the Referral Exclusion List. I've mostly used this to just cancel out links from other sites in our domain structure; subdoimain.foosite.com -> foosite.com, but decided to investigate adding PayPal to this and came across [this support doc from Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en).

After reading that article I wondered what would happen. The result = NO MORE PAYPAL referrals and referrals from the original source without having to worry about `utm=nooverride=1` usage.

I have verified with a Google support specialist that the below has no negative effects on ecommerce reporting and they have submitted my case to their help team for future use. He also mentioned that this methodology actually recently added which is why there is little documentation about it.

Here is how.

1. Make sure you are using Universal Analytics
2. Admin -> Property Settings -> Tracking Info -> Referral Exclusion List
3. - Add Referral Exclusion
4. Insert referral domain - my case was paypal.com but you may have this issue with others - key here is to identify any domain that might be hijacking ecommerce transactions. So if you are seeing anything that has ecommerce credit that you don't think should; add it

**This should solve the problem but I would suggest taking things a few steps further.**

1. Adjust your session settings. Admin -> Property Settings -> Tracking Info -> Session Settings

   - A few notes about session settings- depending on your site and how users engage I would initially adjust the session timeout so that session is longer than 30 mins. I set mine to 2 hours for testing. Then for campaign timeout I set it 1 day (much shorter time than our normal campaigns.
   - This allowed me to initially see that it was indeed eliminating PayPal from the referral source and but that my transactions in GA matched my internal reports.
   - After verification I set the session timeout to 45 mins - 15 mins longer than our site session settings and set the campaign timeout to 7 days.
2. Make use of Google URL builder and add parameters to your URLs.

   - This is not only good practice it saves you tons of time trying to segment out your referral sources in GA. It is especially helpful if you collect acquisition source in your internal reports or logs because you can compare those to GA to ensure you are getting accurate ecomm numbers from GA.

Comment: I have been trying to solve a similar problem.  But the 3rd party site is a google authentication and not a payment integrator.  I have put accounts.google.com into the Referral Exclusion List.  This stopped the domain from getting credit.  But instead credit is being given to "(direct)" instead of the original referrer.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's tough, the (direct) makes it sound like that it is coming via them putting your website URL directly in the address bar/bookmarks/etc... Direct is technically a good thing to have unless of course it isn't accurate and you know that it is supposed to be from a source. Are you sure that it is from a source vs. legitimate direct traffic?

How exactly are you seeing things up and what sources are you expecting?

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks for solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Let me share my experience with the 'referral exclusion list' in UA:

I added paypal.com and another similar payment provider to the list.

Consequence: 
The traffic attributed to those referrers was reduced from that moment on - but far from beeing zero. (Let's say it was halfed.)

No idea why it is working for parts of the traffic only.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add my answer in case anyone comes across this same issue.

From my understanding the following no longer works with newer GA code:

`utm_nooverride=1`

However if you pass the `_ga` parameter google analytics will be able to relate the two instances before being transferred to paypal. Okay great so all you have to do is add the `_ga` parameter to the return URL...but how do you get it?

Unfortunately you need to grab it client side first:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
   var linkerParam = tracker.get('linkerParam');
});
```

Hope this helps someone.

***Reference***

https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-marketing/t/tracking-true-referrals-in-google-analytics-when-using-paypal-163514

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain

Comment: There's a problem though: Linker parameters are only valid for 2 minutes after they are created. Which means that this works only if the customers spend less than 2 minutes on the payment page, which is an overly optimistic case.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add my experience. I have been having the very same problem, and as you have mentioned the solution is putting paypal.com on the Referral Exclusion List. You must be upgraded to the new Google Universal Analytics in order for to have access to it.

Comment: That is correct UA must be enabled for your property to take advantage of the ability to control session lengths and also to add exclusions to the referral list. I made to make that note in my answer.