# Google Analytics Referrals coming from third party payment provider

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, payment-gateway, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I am using universal analytics on my website via Google Tag Manager with data layer e-commerce tracking enabled.

The referral addresses are appearing to be coming from the payment providers (e.g. secure.arcot5.com)

I have included all my URLS in to the autolinker and after some testing the _ga cookie value appears to be consistent all the way through the booking process but it appears differently on the page after the secure payment takes place.

This suggests the session is being treated as a new one, hence the referral address issue I am having.

I have been trying to set a cookie on the entry page which equals the _ga cookie value but currently I am unable to retreive it on the confirmation page.

Has anyone got any ideas for a possible solution?

You will most definitely save my life!

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this article? There could be a couple of pointers in there however I'm not sure what you have and haven't tried

[Accurately reporting referrer from payments made with PayPal in Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976093/accurately-reporting-referrer-from-payments-made-with-paypal-in-google-analytics)